# How to remove the all the double quotes and allign every thing in perfect format from a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, double-quotes, file-conversion

i would like to remove the double quotes from my below text file. i need to input the file using my C# application and read the text file and then remove all the double quotes and give the output.
I need to remove all the quotes and make them into perfect four spaced format
So how can i do this.

Input file

```
   Designator   Comment Footprint   Center-X(mm)    Center-Y(mm)

     "C5"   "CAP,1n,50V.0603"   "CAPC1608N" "97.733"    "73.025"
     "C4"   "CAP,1n,50V.0603"   "CAPC1608N" "99.638"    "73.025"
     "C3"   "CAP,1n,50V.0603"   "CAPC1608N" "101.543"   "73.025"
     "C7"   "CAP1233,,1n,50V.0603"  "CAPC1608N" "103.448"   "73.025"
     "C8"   "CAP1233,1n,50V.0603"   "CAPC1608N" "105.353"   "73.025"
     "C9"   "CAP455,1n,50V.0603"    "CAPC1608N" "107.258"   "73.025"
     "C10"  "CAP4522,1n,50V.0603"   "CAPC1608N" "109.163"   "73.025"
```

My codes from my C# application to input the text file:

```
private void convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\files";
        ofd.Filter = "TXT files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        ofd.FilterIndex = 2;
        ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int[] cols = new int[] { 15, 30, 15, 20, 12 };
            string[] strLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string line = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < strLines.Length; i++)
            {
                line = RemoveWhiteSpace(strLines[i]).Trim(); // here i am getting error in RemoveWhiteSpace, that it is not in the context
                string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
                    sb.Append(cells[c].PadRight(cols[c]));
                sb.Append("\r\n");
            }

            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }
}
```

How can i do this? Please help me out.

I would like to get the format in below style for all the text file i input. So for the above text file i would like to get the format as shown below

```
     Designator    Comment          Footprint   Center-X(mm)    Center-Y(mm)

       C5      CAP,1n,50V.0603      CAPC1608N     97.733          73.025
       C4      CAP,1n,50V.0603      CAPC1608N     99.638          73.025
       C3      CAP,1n,50V.0603      CAPC1608N     101.543         73.025
       C7      CAP,1n,50V.0603      CAPC1608N     103.448         73.025
       C8      CAP,1n,50V.0603      CAPC1608N     105.353         73.025
       C9      CAP,1n,50V.0603      CAPC1608N     107.258         73.025
       C10     CAP,1n,50V.0603      CAPC1608N     109.163         73.025
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this example, This will remove the double quotes and reformat your text.

```
private void Reformat(string fileName)
{
    //Give the column width according to column index.
    int[] cols = new int[] { 12, 35, 25, 15, 15 };
    string[] strLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string line = string.Empty;
    string LastComment = string.Empty;
    string CarouselName = "Carousel";
    int iCarousel = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strLines.Length; i++)
    {
        line = RemoveWhiteSpace(strLines[i]).Trim();
        string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');                    
        for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
            sb.Append(cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(cols[c]));

        if (cells.Length > 1)
        {
            if (cells[1] != LastComment & i > 0)
            {
                iCarousel++;
                if (iCarousel > 45)
                   iCarousel = 1;
                LastComment = cells[1];
            }

            if (i == 0)
                sb.Append("Location".PadRight(15));
            else
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0}:{1}", CarouselName, iCarousel).PadRight(15));
        }
        sb.Append("\r\n");
    }

    //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}


private string RemoveWhiteSpace(string str)
{
    str = str.Replace("  ", " ");
    if (str.Contains("  "))
        str = RemoveWhiteSpace(str);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: here i am getting error in RemoveWhiteSpace, that it is not in the context

Comment: u r there.. could you give me a request for chat in stackover flow

Answer (score 3):

The two steps are to read the file and replace the quote marks with nothing.

```
string allText = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName); //read file
string noQuotes = allText.Replace("\"", ""); //replace text
```

Strings are immutable which is why `Replace` returns a new string object instead of simply changing the existing `allText` string.

Alternatively, you may want to use [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) instead which will return an array of strings where each element is one line of the text file. The theory is the same but you would iterate the array and replace the quotes in each element with the empty string.

If you want to use ReadAllLines and WriteAllLines (to save the file out), you could do this

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"saveFile.txt", File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName)
                                   .Select(s => s.Replace("\"", "")).ToList());
```

That will do the reading, replacing, and saving in one line (not that fewer number of lines is always better).

Comment: `Error4 'System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog' does not contain a definition for 'Filename' and no extension method 'Filename' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Sorry, it should be `FileName` with a capital `N` (I've updated it in the answer)

Comment: its taking the file and how can i save the converted file

Comment: You can use [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The latter if you used `ReadAllLines`.

Comment: yes i got it but what above the format.. Please look my question once more.. i have added one thing.. about the format

Comment: Did you try with `WriteAllLines` instead? It should maintain linebreaks. What does your output look like?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? Is the file that's being outputted, called "saveFile.txt" in the example above, the same as the original file selected? Don't forget, the file being selected is not being overwritten in the code above, a new file is being created (called saveFile.txt but you can change that to whatever you like)

Comment: now its showing error `Error 8 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: also .. `Error 9 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]'`

Comment: please give the old code what you sai was true i was trying to open the old original file

Comment: Looks like you're targetting .NET 3.5. Change the `ToList` to `ToArray`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
using System.IO;

File.WriteAllText(@"C:/text2.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"C:/text1.txt").Replace("\"", ""));
```

Update: Shorter solution

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with regular expressions:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string withoutQuotes = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName), "\"", "");
    File.WriteAllText(ofd.FileName, withoutQuotes);
}
```

Comment: this worked but my format is went.. how can i get the  correct format